# How do i get apt-get to work on ubuntu on aws instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apt-get

I have instantiated an ubuntu instance in a custom vpc.
I can connect to the instance. I have configured NACL and a security group.
I find I can only get apt-get update to work when i make a custom TCP rule on the inbound interface of the NACL that allows ports 1024-65535.

I do not think this is a very secure solution. This is probably due to my lack of unterstanding of apt-get, but it seems that the response is coming back in on an ephemeral port, but from what I have read in forums it only supposed to need port 80?
Here are my inbound rules with rule 95 being the rule that will allow it to work:
[image]

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS NACL is stateless, so that you need to allow inbound return traffic for the response on ephemeral ports that you request.

```
Source: 0.0.0.0/0 
Protocol: TCP
Port Rage: 32768-65535 
Allow/Deny: ALLOW
```

If your intent really was to use stateless firewall like NACL for high security requirement or compliance requirement. This AWS doc describes it very well https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-recommended-nacl-rules.html#nacl-rules-scenario-1

But, enable only security group would be suffice for general usage cases.